# Minecraft Plugin scheduleSyncDelayedTask Error

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I have a problem and am new at making Minecraft plugins and writing code in general.

I am trying to make a plugin that waits about 15 seconds before executing the second command however the code I have now has an error when I try to do (plugin, new Runnable(). I have done some research and it most people say that is because I don't have this in my Main class. The problem is that I don't want it in my Main. So I was wondering what I have to do to make this work.

Code below. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.
~Stone

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {


    if (sender instanceof Player){
        //checks to see if player sent command
        Player player = (Player) sender;


        if (args.length >= 1) {
            //too many arguments message
            player.sendMessage(Utils.chat("&4There were too many arguments, I could not complete that command"));

        }


        if (player.hasPermission("reloadc.use")) {
            //reloads server, sends message, and stores variable value              
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Utils.chat("&6Server will be reloaded in 15 seconds by &5" + player.getDisplayName()));

            Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Utils.chat("&6This works"));
                }
            }, 20L);

            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Utils.chat("&6IT WORKED!!!!!"));                
        }

        else if (!player.hasPermission("reloadc.use")) {

            player.sendMessage(Utils.chat("&4You do not have permission to reload the server"));
            player.sendMessage(Utils.chat("&5If you belive this is a mistake please contact an admin"));

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

The Code that is giving me problems is right here (the word plugin)

```
                Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Utils.chat("&6This works"));
                }
            }, 20L);
```

Here are 3 images with the errors that it is giving me. The only change that i did not make was the getServer(). because it gave me more errors and did not change anything for the better at least from what I can tell.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Ljx.png)[[image: Image 1: Screenshot of error Eclipse gave me]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6JaG.png)
[[image: Image 2: Screenshot of error Eclipse gave me (plugin is underlined in red)]][image: Image 3: Screenshot of the CMD from my server when I tried to excecute my reloadc command]

Ok So I have completed the changes, everything says that it works but now when I run the command that I setup it does everything it should except wait for 15 seconds. It executes the text one after the other telling me that it will be reloaded in 15 seconds and then at the same time it tells me it worked. Nothing seems wrong to me now, it just says that it is running fine and my wait time is 300L which is server ticks. That should equal 15.

Images of completed code below.

[image: My Main Class][image: Image of my Reload C class with the wait 15 seconds method inside.]

Comment: I have updated my answer to give a solution to your problem. Simply replace `plugin` with `this` on the line that is giving you the issue.

Comment: So we actually do have all of this in a separate class and I don't know how or where to reference this plugin variable I tried putting this inside of my method under the Public Boolean On Command before the if statements started but it was givng me "cannot initiate type Plugin"

Comment: Plugin plugin = new Plugin(); Sorry didn't know enter would send it, that is the line of code I tried. What would you advise I do?

Comment: Did you try replacing `plugin` with `this` in your original code? Like so `Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {`

Comment: Ahh I see your problem. Please show me how the code at the top of your listener/event class, and show me how you call the lister class from your main class. You basically need to pass a reference of `this` from the main class into your listener/event class and then you can successfully use `plugin`.

Comment: I have altered my answer to show you how to pass the plugin variable to your command class.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your responses, it's starting to look really promising, I did what you said and now my reloadC class has no errors but when I tried to follow what you said and insert the new ReloadC(this); command it underlined it in red and seemed to want me to remove the "this" however neither of these cases worked after trying it. I will add the new screenshots with my code to the post.

Comment: I see you have made an edit but you have uploaded the same image twice. You need to add this method to your RoloadC class `public ReloadC(Main plugin){this.plugin = plugin; }` so that you don't get errors in your main class. Also, try to keep the old/original content in the post, so that if anyone has the same issue later they can follow the changes.

Comment: OMG never mind that last section it works correctly now. I figured out I just was not waiting the 15 seconds to see the text saying this works pop up. I forgot that i had left a broadcast message command that said IT WORKED in all caps right after the pause.  Thank you again for all of your help, really appreciate it! ~Stone

Comment: Awesome to hear! Don't forget to accept the answer, and thanks for putting all the content back. Hopefully it can help anyone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your update/edit:

Your error happens because you use `plugin` does not mean anything to your code. You need to declare it as a variable before you use in there, or assuming that you wrote all the code in one class for your plugin then you can easily replace `plugin` with `this` like so `Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {`.

If it is in another class then to declare the variable you need to pass it in from another class or call it from your Main plugin class. The following will show you haw to pass it to your listener class.

In your main plugin class you need to do this, note how we add `this` to the function that is calling your command class `new CommandClass(this)` note that your class will have a different name than `CommandClass`:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
  @Override
  public void onEnable(){
    new CommandClass(this);
  }
}
```

And then in the command class, we modify it to receive the variable `public CommandClass(Main plugin)`:

```
public class CommandClass implements CommandExecutor{
  private Main plugin;

  public CommandClass(Main plugin){
    this.plugin = plugin;
  }
}
```

Now your onCommand method will work because you have a reference to `plugin` in your class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
            Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Utils.chat("&6This works"));
        }
    }, 300L);
}
```

---

Original answer edited a little to include some of the response to your screenshots:

I can see four problems:

1. Your error happens because you have not referenced your actual plugin, but just typed `plugin`.
2. Please note that the delay is in server ticks, so 20L will only have
   a delay of 1 second. If you want 15 seconds delay then use 300L.
3. You didn't use the `@Override` annotation, but it is very important for the runnable task.
4. You could use `getServer().getScheduler()` instead of `Bukkit.getScheduler()`, just in case there is something funky going on with your code and you have managed to start more than one instance of the server.

Here is an updated version of your code with 1 and 3 fixed:

```
        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Utils.chat("&6This works"));
            }
        }, 300L);
```

Here is an updated version of your code with suggestion 4 included:

```
        getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Utils.chat("&6This works"));
            }
        }, 300L);
```