# Spigot Could not pass event BlockPlaceEvent to plugin v1.0

Tags: java

So I've been trying to code an easy plugin that removes a block .5 seconds or 10 ticks after you place it. But I've been running into some problems. When I placed a block to test it I got this error stated below and since I'm not very experienced in programming I don't know how to fix it. Help would be appreciated.

My error is:

```
11:32:29 ERROR]: Could not pass event BlockPlaceEvent to firstPlugin v1.0
java.lang.ClassCastException: class me.chappiemwoan.firstPlugin.events.firstPluginEvents cannot be cast to class org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin (me.chappiemwoan.firstPlugin.events.firstPluginEvents is in unnamed module of loader org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader @1f0389ee; org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at me.chappiemwoan.firstPlugin.events.firstPluginEvents.blockTimer(firstPluginEvents.java:40) ~[?:?]
        at com.destroystokyo.paper.event.executor.asm.generated.GeneratedEventExecutor1.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.EventExecutor.lambda$create$1(EventExecutor.java:69) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at co.aikar.timings.TimedEventExecutor.execute(TimedEventExecutor.java:80) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:607) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.event.CraftEventFactory.callBlockPlaceEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:378) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.ItemStack.placeItem(ItemStack.java:280) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerInteractManager.a(PlayerInteractManager.java:533) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1535) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(PacketPlayInUseItem.java:27) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(PacketPlayInUseItem.java:5) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$ensureMainThread$1(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:23) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:136) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:109) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.bb(MinecraftServer.java:1136) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:1129) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:119) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:1090) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1004) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:177) ~[patched_1.16.4.jar:git-Paper-276]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
```

Here is my code below.

```
    package me.chappiemwoan.firstPlugin.events;

import me.chappiemwoan.firstPlugin.*;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import me.chappiemwoan.firstPlugin.Override;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityPickupItemEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerPickupItemEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;

public class firstPluginEvents implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public static void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "WELCOME TO THE SERVER");

    }

    @EventHandler
    public static void onItemPickUp(PlayerPickupItemEvent event1) {
        Player player1 = event1.getPlayer();
        player1.kickPlayer("haha you thought");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void blockTimer(BlockPlaceEvent event2) {
        Block block = event2.getBlock();
        Location location = block.getLocation();

        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask((Plugin) this, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                location.getBlock().setType(Material.AIR);
            }
        }, 10L);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i now found out that the timer is definitely the problem. without the timer it works perfectly. I almost certainly know that the problem is in this part,               `((plugin) this, new Runnable()`
I do not know how to fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have figured it out or not by now, but I had the same problem and after doing some digging I found that the "plugin" part is not defined in the class that you are writing that code in.  If you use that code in the main class it should work fine, but since you trying to run it in a different class "firstpluginevents" it does not know what "plugin" means.  You have to put the top code in your main class "on_enable" and the bottom piece in your "firstpluginevents" class.  This will tell your plugin that "plugin" means the actual plugin that you are writing.  This link goes into a bit more detail about that.

Put this in your main class:

```
new firstPluginEvents(this);
```

Put this in your "firstPluginEvetns" class:

```
private MainClass plugin;

public firstPluginEvents(MainClass plugin){
    this.plugin = plugin;
}
```

[Minecraft Plugin scheduleSyncDelayedTask Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867044/minecraft-plugin-schedulesyncdelayedtask-error)